# Data structure for recognizing repeat values

Tags: c#, data-structures

I am running a fairly large search, and am getting a System.OutOfMemoryException.

The problem is I am storing a string key for each state I have previously visited as a `HashSet<sting>`. Once this gets to around 7 million elements, it crashes. My thought is that I don't need to be able to retrieve the strings, only recognize if it exists in the set.

I seem to remember a specialized data structure for this kind of thing, but I can't remember the name of it for the life of me. If I recall correctly it had fairly constant memory requirements and you add elements to it, and it can tell you with some degree of certainty whether you have already added some value to it. Am I making this up, or does this exist. Any tips?

Comment: What sort of search are you doing. Searching for cycles in linked lists, substrings in strings? It will affect the design greatly.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what you're actually doing?  You're visiting some things, which you're representing as a string, and you just want to see at each point whether or not you've been there before?

Comment: I need to avoid repeating states. In order to do so I get a string that uniquely identifies each state I visit and store it. If I try to visit that state again, I can recognize it and not do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no standard collection in .NET  for this, but you can store *alot* of strings in a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) ,using a lot less space than e.g. a hashtable/set

Answer (score 3):

You're probably thinking of a [Bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter).  It gives you a probabilistic result when you check if a string is in the set.  If it is, you'll always find it.  If it isn't, you still might detect that it is, depending on what else in in your set.  Its memory requirements do change based on the number of unique elements you add, but it's *far* below what an HashSet would take up.

Comment: Yes! That is it! I would accept this, but I really do like nos' idea to use a trie.

Answer (score 2):

I think u meant [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure. A trie can be used to replace a hash table, over which it has the following advantages:

- Looking up data in a trie is faster in the worst case, O(m) time, compared to an imperfect hash table. An imperfect hash table can have key collisions. A key collision is the hash function mapping of different keys to the same position in a hash table. The worst-case lookup speed in an imperfect hash table is O(N) time, but far more typically is O(1), with O(m) time spent evaluating the hash.
- There are no collisions of different keys in a trie.
- Buckets in a trie which are analogous to hash table buckets that store key collisions are only necessary if a single key is associated with more than one value.
- There is no need to provide a hash function or to change hash functions as more keys are added to a trie.
- A trie can provide an alphabetical ordering of the entries by key.

Answer (score 1):

[Bloom Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the Dictionary class?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

An excerpt from MSDN:

> Every key in a Dictionary must be unique according to
>   the dictionary's equality comparer. A
>   key cannot be null, but a value can
>   be, if the value type TValue is a
>   reference type.

You can use the `ContainsKey` method to check to see if an entry has already been inserted before inserting a new record.

Comment: Yes, that is true, but the storage required by a dictionary is linear to the number of elements. I need something that uses less memory.